# Disabling Windows 10 update forever, Embedded use

Tags: windows, windows-10, embedded

I have 50 computers with windows 10 pro

- I disabled Windows Update Service
- I connected them to internet once to activate the windows

These will be on 24/7 for an embedded project and never connected to internet. 
 There should be no prompts or interruptions, restarts or warnings. The questions is, will windows continue working with this configuration? Or will it cause restarts/warnings?

It think this was a big mistake to get windows 10 pro. Windows IoT would be better.

Comment: no internet, no updates, simple. You can't guarantee 24/7 so be resilient to reboots, power loss.

Comment: If there is no connection to the internet then no updates will be installed.  However, you should keep the system updated, at least do it once a year.  Simply for quality of life improvements.  The only exception are Windows Insider Build, those do expire, release channel builds **never** expire

Comment: Windows IoT is not a desktop operating system and cannot be used like one.